# List returned from function is empty, Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, math

I'm writing a program in Python to better understand my linear algebra course.
I'm trying to use a function to get the RREF form of an input matrix. The function works and prints what it should. When I return what it printed ( code below ) and access that returned value, it will not provide a list. Instead, it returns `[]`.
How can I access the returned value as a list?

Here's the function:

```
def rref(matrix_given):
    global rref_matrix
    rref_matrix = [[c for c in matrix_given[i]] for i in range(len(matrix_given))]
    print(rref_matrix)
    leading_one = 0
    rowCount = len(rref_matrix)
    columnCount = len(rref_matrix[0])
    for row in range(rowCount):
        if columnCount <= leading_one:
            break
        r = row
        while rref_matrix[r][leading_one] == 0:
            r += 1
            if rowCount == r:
                r = row
                leading_one += 1
                if columnCount == leading_one:
                    print(rref_matrix)
                    return 0
        rref_matrix[r], rref_matrix[row] = rref_matrix[row], rref_matrix[r]
        if rref_matrix[row][leading_one] != 0:
            rref_matrix[row][:] = [x / rref_matrix[row][leading_one] for x in rref_matrix[row]]
        for new_row in range(len(rref_matrix)):
            if new_row != row:
                rref_matrix[new_row][:] = [x - (rref_matrix[new_row][leading_one] * rref_matrix[row][rref_matrix[new_row].index(x)]) for x in rref_matrix[new_row]] 
        leading_one += 1
        print(rref_matrix)
    return rref_matrix
```

And I access it as follows:

```
rref_transposed = [row for row in rref(list(zip(*matrix)))]
    print(rref_transposed)
```

It prints `[]`.

What am I not seeing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it `0` or `[0]`?

Comment: Thank you for the format help. It returns an empty list. @Ev.Kounis

Comment: difficult to understand what it does. do you have sample input and output? what does `rref_matrix` print ?

Comment: There is no reason for `rref_matrix` to be global. That could be the cause of so many issues that we would never be able to debug for you. **Never** use `global` is pretty good advice; get rid of it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

There is an indentation problem with your print statement. It should be moved left by 1 tab.
The code you post will never run this way. Furthermore you declared a global variable with no reason at all and your function is completely unreadable for an external people.

The [0] returned by the call you mention but you didn't post here is probably returned by your

> return 0

Statement at line 19. Maybe your function should not enter to that if but it is not possible to say that for sure because I have no idea about what are you doing with your code!
I hope my hints will help you ;)